# Monthly payments using Stripe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, payment, stripe-payments, subscription

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and am using the Stripe service for user payments. I am setting up a feature so that each month, a payment is made to the Stripe service for a users subscription.

Currently, I am using Hangfire, with a recurring monthly task for this. Each month, a payment is made to Stripe, and if the payment is successful, the users account in the MVC application is extended by 1 month.

My question is this: Should I setup a subscription with Stripe, and have a webhook that is called after a monthly payment is made. In the webhook, if the payment is successful, the users account in the MVC application is extended by 1 month.

Does anyone have some coding advice on the best way to setup a monthly payment for a users account when using MVC 5?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stripe's [subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions) will automatically charge your customer every month so there shouldn't be any need for a recurring task on your end to build this.

First you would create a monthly plan in the [dashboard](https://admin.stripe.com/plans) so that you can subscribe your customers later. Then you would call the [Create Customer API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) and pass the plan identifier as the `plan` parameter.

You customer would then get immediately charged the plan price and then charge each month on the same day until you cancel the subscription.

Comment: Helpfull :) Was just googling and found this post.